# how to fix the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Value' of null

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I'm  trying to fix the error but it's  still saying  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Value' of null in console  here is html and js

```js
function generateCV() {
    // console.log("hello");

    let nameField = document.getElementById("nameField").Value;
    let nameT1 =document.getElementById("nameT1");

    nameT1.innerHTML=nameField;

    //direct

    document.getElementById('nameT2').innerHTML=nameField
}
```

```html
          

  <div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nameField1" >Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="nameField"  class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter here here">
          </div>
      <div class="container text-center mt-3">
              <button onclick="generateCV()" 
              class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Generate cv</button>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
            <p id="nameT1">Robin</p>
</div>
```

Comment: did you ensure that the DOM is fully loaded before calling `getElementById()` ?

Comment: fix this line -> let nameField = document.getElementById("nameField").value; Change value to lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` should be in lower case. Thats why you get undefined when you get document for nameField node value. for nameField.

```
 let nameField = document.getElementById("nameField").value;
```

Comment: OMG now working, silly mistake I  made  THANKS RITIK SINGH

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: And I was trying to fix this problem  from last five hours

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="nameField"  class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter here here">
```

You were missing a quotation mark.

Comment: well spotted!   .

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. Post a comment and mark the question as typo instead.

Comment: Sorry didnt know, im new ! Will do in the future

Comment: show undefined after put the quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```js
let nameField = document.getElementById("nameField")?.value;
```

and add the good id in the search document.getElementById because your html doesn't have the id you search so it return null and you check value of null so it crash
also... use value in lower case ;)

Comment: i tried,  but it's show undefined in output section

Comment: that's because Saren typed the Id as `nameField1` instead of `nameField`